# Using XPath in Safari 6 web inspector

Tags: xpath, safari, web-inspector

Safari's Web Inspector lets you do XPath queries from the search box:

[image: web inspector screenshot]

But the box is too small! You can use it but not comfortably.

Is it possible to do the XPath query from the console prompt shown on the bottom of the screenshot?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think in the console of Chrome or Firefox or Safari you can evaluate XPath expressions with the function `$x` e.g. `$x('//span')` selects all `span` elements.